# PHP - dynamically get class name in static member function

Tags: php, polymorphism

I have the following hiearchy:

```
class A {
    public static function getClass() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

class B extends A {}

class C extends B {}
```

without overriding getClass() in either B or C, I would like the following output:

```
echo A::getClass() // A
echo B::getClass() // B
echo C::getClass() // C
```

Currently, all of the above simply output A. How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: In case of `__CLASS__` did you try `get_class($this)`?

Comment: I cannot use $this since I do not have any instances - the methods are static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
class A {
    public static function getClass() {
        return get_called_class();
    }
}

class B extends A {}

class C extends B {}
```

[Here's the demo](https://eval.in/152948)

Comment: I just hate it when there is a standard function which does *exactly* what I want, and I gloss right over it. Thank you so much for pointing this out.